# Bootstrap - col-size not working when imported bootstrap scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

My problem is in boostrap grid. When I import bootstrap.scss to my component, col-size not working.
Here is my code:

**test.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: red;">HELLO WORLD</div>
    <div class="col-8" style="background-color: green;">HELLO WORLD</div>
    <div class="col-2" style="background-color: blue;">HELLO WORLD</div>
</div>
```

this works as I expect. But, when I import the file bootstrap.scss, it will be displayed col full size:

**test.component.sass**

```
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you import your test.component.sass file ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I use Angular